In deployed next.js app, my images are not displaying in the dynamic route pages. In the static ones, It works well. How can I fix it?
I have images under my public folder. I can see all images in the development but there is a problem in deployment. The path works well in the static rendered pages and I can see my images. However, my images are not displaying in the dynamic rendered pages. How can I solve this problem? My next.js version is +13.
I updated my nex.config.js folder like that: config file
My folder structure is like that: folder structure
I can not access the images in the deployment from credit-card class:credit card class

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Could you please try to add domain details to next.config.js file like
images: {     domains: ['secure.gravatar.com', 'abc.express.com'],     unoptimized: true,  },
Also please share the URL of the website so I can take more closer look.

My url is https://kredikiyasla.com. First page is static rendering so there is no problem. If you choose "Kredi Kartları", you will see the problem. My images are in my local, I am not fetching them. Still, should I edit this:  images: {     domains: ['secure.gravatar.com', 'abc.express.com'],     unoptimized: true,  }
